# Angular ag-grid button always being disabled on load - want it enabled

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

So I am trying to do a simple Angular ag-grid and new to Angular. I have a delete button that I would like to be enabled, and have a customRenderer for it, but it is always putting disabled attribute when creating the element.

In my constructor, I am building a simple grid:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.columnDefs = [
        {field: "email", headerName: "Email Address", colId: "email", width: 200, editable: true},
        {headerName: '', field: 'changeButton', colId: "changeButton", width: 25, cellRenderer: this.changeButtonRenderer, filter: false, sortable: false},
        {headerName: '', field: 'deleteButton', colId: "deleteButton", width: 25, cellRenderer: this.deleteButtonRenderer, filter: false, sortable: false}
    ];
  
  this.getEmails();}
```

In my deleteButtonRenderer, I am building the button WITHOUT the disabled attribute:

```
deleteButtonRenderer(params) {
   var eDiv = document.createElement('div');
   
   eDiv.innerHTML = '<div class="bs-component"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btnDelete">Delete</button></div>';
   var eButton = eDiv.querySelector("#btnDelete") as HTMLInputElement;
   var _me = params;
   
   console.log(eButton);
   
   eButton.disabled = false;

   console.log(eButton);
```

But when I look at my console log, I am seeing the following outputted for both eButton outputs:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btnDelete" disabled>Delete</button>
```

And in my grid it is showing as disabled. I have tried numerous attempts to get this to be enabled. Not sure what I am doing wrong. This is my grid config:

```
            <ag-grid-angular 
                style="width: 850px; 
                height: 500px; 
                text-align: center;" 
                class="ag-theme-balham" 
                [rowData]="rowData" 
                [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
                [enableFilter]="true"
                [pagination]="true"
                [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
                (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
                [components]="components"
                [rowHeight]="35"
                [overlayLoadingTemplate]="overlayLoadingTemplate"
                [overlayNoRowsTemplate]="overlayLoadingTemplate">
            </ag-grid-angular>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Probably something stupid I am missing, but still a newb.

Thank you!
phi

Comment: i tried your code to reproduce the error but couldn't reproduce it. check [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/zdaEyotUVbprEtmg). I suspect something else is doin this. may be JS or CSS rule?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, something is doing it. I have tried taking the CSS off the html rendered element, but no dice. Will keep looking, thanks again!

Comment: Strange part, is when I output to console right after, it is showing the "disabled" attribute in the output. Even though I am explicitly not putting it there.